# Create a dictionary iterating two lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, error-handling

I'm building this dictionary that has as values the index of the list in which the animals appears.

I have this two lists:

```
list1 = ['cow', 'fish', 'monkey', 'lion', 'cat', 'elephant', 'tiger', 'dog']
list2 = [[['dog', 'cat', 'elephant', 'monkey'], ['dog', 'lion', 'tiger'], ['fish', 'dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'cow']]
```

And iterating through them I'm building my dictionary

```
dict = {}

for i in list1:
    for index, item in enumerate(list2):
        if i in item:
            if i in dict.keys():
                dict[i].append(index)
        else:
            dict[i] = index
```

The problem is: when it finds an item already in the dictionary keys, instead of just adding the index to the set of values it gaves me this error

```
dict[i].append(index)

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'
```

The expected output should be:

```
dict = {'cow':[2], 'cat':[0,2], 'fish':[2], 'dog':[0,2], 'monkey':[0], 'lion':[1], 'elephant':[0], 'tiger':[1]}
```

Comment: could you also add the expected output? may be there is a better solution using Python constructs.

Comment: I have added the expected output, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the indentation issue, you need to create a list for the first time. Currently, you are assigning it as the element so `append()` won't work.

```
list1 = ['cow', 'fish', 'monkey', 'lion', 'cat', 'elephant', 'tiger', 'dog']
list2 = [
            ['dog', 'cat', 'elephant', 'monkey'], 
            ['dog', 'lion', 'tiger'], 
            ['fish', 'dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'cow']
        ]

dct = {}
for i in list1:
    for index, item in enumerate(list2):
        if i in item:
            if i in dct.keys():
                dct[i].append(index)
            else:
                dct[i] = [index]
```

Output:

```
{'cow': [2], 'fish': [2], 'monkey': [0], 'lion': [1], 'cat': [0, 2], 'elephant': [0], 'tiger': [1], 'dog': [0, 1, 2]}
```

Further, don't use `dict()` for object names to avoid over shadowing built-in objects.

You could also use `setdefault` to get rid of the `if-else` logic as:

```
dct = {}
for i in list1:
    for index, item in enumerate(list2):
        if i in item:
            dct.setdefault(i, []).append(index)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following could be a one-line solution that ensures the removal of duplicates using sets:

```
d = {a: set(d.get(a, []) + [i]) for i, l in enumerate(list2) for a in l if a in list1}
print(d)
```

This is the output:

```
{
    'dog': {0, 1, 2},
    'cat': {0, 2},
    'elephant': {0},
    'monkey': {0},
    'lion': {1},
    'tiger': {1},
    'fish': {2},
    'cow': {2},
}
```